# FB.Canvas.setSize() is not working for me, is anyone else having this issue?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I use FB.Canvas.setSize() for all my apps, it is currently not working and defaults to the height of around 800px high. Is anyone else having this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was a Facebook issue and beyond dev control.